# Do something when tab active, ExtJs

Tags: javascript, extjs

I have a tap panel, and OpenLayers map on the page. I want to show one layer when one tap is active. How to do this? I mean how to do some action when tab active, and destroy this whan panel is no active?

Comment: Please add some source code. It will be more helpful and goes faster for the helpers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can listen to `tabchange` event as mentioned here http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/api/Ext.tab.Panel-event-tabchange
like this

```
{
 xtype:'tabpanel'
 //some other configs
 listeners:{
  tabchange:function(tabPabel,newCard, oldCard){
   //chek wether the newCard is same to what you wanted
   // and do whatever you wanna do
  }
 }
}
```

Comment: `newCard` and `oldCard` this is a Tabs?  Okay.   But how to stop doing something  when this Tap no more active?

Comment: same event will be raise when active tab changes so you can check and see if the oldTab is the tab for which you wanna set the event.

Comment: `listeners:{``'activate' : function(){` `alert("PRIVET DETKA"); `
     `}`
    `},` This is what i want.

Comment: activate and deactivate events depend more upon the visual state.. if by chance you change a tab but currently the tab panel isnt visible this event wont be fired..